# Expected identifier before numeric constant while getting the UIScreen size

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this code:

Updated

```
-(IBAction)editDrivers:(id)sender
{
    selDriverBrand = driverBrand;
    selDriverModel = driverModel;
    selDriverSize = driverSize;
    driverParams *IView = [[driverParams alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    CGRect onScreenFrame = IView.view.frame;
    //CGRect offScreenFrame = self.view.frame;
    CGRect offScreenFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
                 //  ^Fails on this line.
}
```

and I'm getting an expected identifier before numeric constant error on the indicated line, but I can't figure out for the life of me why, I am doing the same thing in other functions without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did get it to work dynamically, instead I ended up checking for the iPad and then setting the origin accordingly:

```
-(IBAction)editDrivers:(id)sender
{
    selDriverBrand = driverBrand;
    selDriverModel = driverModel;
    selDriverSize = driverSize;
    driverParams *IView = [[driverParams alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    CGRect onScreenFrame = IView.view.frame;
    CGRect offScreenFrame = self.view.frame;

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    { offScreenFrame.origin.y = 1024; }
    else
    { offScreenFrame.origin.y = 480; }

    IView.view.frame = offScreenFrame;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"FakeModalTransition" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5f];
    [self.view addSubview:IView.view];
    IView.view.frame = onScreenFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the value of `y` as it is a constant. To do what you want you need to create a new frame with the value of `y` that you desire and then assign it to `offScreenFrame`

```
CGRect onScreenFrame = IView.view.frame;
CGRect offScreenFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same "Expected identifier before numeric constant" error along with a few other errors now too.

Comment: Can you update your code pls, you may have different kind of problem like missing character, or invalid character somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
offScreenFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,  self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this line fails:

`CGRect offScreenFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);`

Then `self` is not a `UIViewController`.

Additionally:

ivars and vars should begin with a lowercase letter by convention--which ARC requires. So `IView` would be better as: `iView` (and syntax highligting would also be correct).

Class names should begin with a uppercase letter in order to follow conventions. `driverParams` would be better as `DriverParams`.

All this makes the code more readable to others.

Comment: I get the same error using something like [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height;

Comment: Also, I can get a result from this code:NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame)); but I can't get just the width or height with similar calls.